# What happened with SourceForge UbuntuZilla repository?

Tags: apt, repository

I have several Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS machines with added UbuntuZilla repository:

```
grep -v ^# /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list | grep http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/ubuntuzilla/mozilla/apt
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/ubuntuzilla/mozilla/apt all main
```

I added this repository to get SeaMonkey deb-package:

```
$ apt-cache policy seamonkey-mozilla-build 
seamonkey-mozilla-build:
  Installed: 2.49.2-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 2.49.2-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 2.49.2-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/ubuntuzilla/mozilla/apt all/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

This week `sudo apt-get update` shows errors about this repository:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
...
Get:8 https://downloads.sourceforge.net/#!/project/ubuntuzilla/mozilla/apt all InRelease [652 B]
Err:8 https://downloads.sourceforge.net/#!/project/ubuntuzilla/mozilla/apt all InRelease
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
...
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/ubuntuzilla/mozilla/apt/dists/all/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

If I download this file manually with `wget` I get:

```
$ wget -O - http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/ubuntuzilla/mozilla/apt/dists/all/InRelease
--2018-03-03 12:54:38--  http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/ubuntuzilla/mozilla/apt/dists/all/InRelease
Resolving downloads.sourceforge.net (downloads.sourceforge.net)... 13.33.76.19
Connecting to downloads.sourceforge.net (downloads.sourceforge.net)|13.33.76.19|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://downloads.sourceforge.net/#!/project/ubuntuzilla/mozilla/apt/dists/all/InRelease [following]
--2018-03-03 12:54:38--  https://downloads.sourceforge.net/
Connecting to downloads.sourceforge.net (downloads.sourceforge.net)|13.33.76.19|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 652 [text/html]
Saving to: ‘STDOUT’

-                                       0%[                                                                       ]       0  --.-KB/s               <html><head>
<title>SourceForge</title>
<!-- <script src="/js/jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://sourceforge.net/js/mirrors.js"></script>
<script src="/js/sf.js"></script>
<script>
var DR_loc = DR_parse_hash_url();
if (DR_loc) {
    DR_sf_main(DR_loc);
} else {
    window.location.href = 'https://sourceforge.net/home.html';
}
</script>
</head><body>
<noscript>
We're sorry -- the Sourceforge site is currently in Disaster Recovery mode, and currently requires
the use of javascript to function.  Please check back later.
</noscript>
</body></html>
-                                     100%[======================================================================>]     652  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2018-03-03 12:54:38 (69,5 MB/s) - written to stdout [652/652]
```

I'm not sure about message **"We're sorry -- the Sourceforge site is currently in Disaster Recovery mode, and currently requires the use of javascript to function.  Please check back later."**.

What should I do?

Note: the same html file is returned when I install/reinstall `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` package (has files on `http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [SourceForge.net Twitter](https://mobile.twitter.com/sfnet_ops) they really have disaster:

> **SourceForge SF.net Operations**  @sfnet_ops · Mar 3
>   We are still working around the clock to restore full capacity to SourceForge. We do not have an ETA yet but we will update here when we do. We appreciate your patience. Thank you.
>
> **SourceForge SF.net Operations** @sfnet_ops · Mar 2
>   We now have a much better idea as to what is causing the recent performance issues. We're now executing a plan to get SourceForge back to full capacity. We may be some hours off yet, but our team is working around the clock until stability is restored. Thank you for your patience
>
> **SourceForge SF.net Operations** @sfnet_ops · Mar 1
>   SourceForge is experiencing issues. We are investigating.
>
> **SourceForge SF.net Operations** @sfnet_ops · Feb 26
>   We are still working to restore full capacity after today's DDOS event. Updates to follow.

**Update 1:** they [are online since 6:45 AM · Mar 4, 2018](https://mobile.twitter.com/sfnet_ops/status/970143157307559936)

> **SourceForge SF.net Operations** @sfnet_ops · 6:45 AM · Mar 4, 2018
>   SourceForge is back online.

but ubuntuzilla is still unavailable:

```
$ wget -O - http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/ubuntuzilla/mozilla/apt
--2018-03-04 14:14:46--  http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/ubuntuzilla/mozilla/apt
Resolving downloads.sourceforge.net (downloads.sourceforge.net)... 216.105.38.13
Connecting to downloads.sourceforge.net (downloads.sourceforge.net)|216.105.38.13|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2018-03-04 14:14:52 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

and files from `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` too:

```
$ wget -O - http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/andale32.exe
--2018-03-04 14:16:46--  http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/andale32.exe
Resolving downloads.sourceforge.net (downloads.sourceforge.net)... 216.105.38.13
Connecting to downloads.sourceforge.net (downloads.sourceforge.net)|216.105.38.13|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2018-03-04 14:16:52 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

**Update 2:** downloads [are fixed](https://mobile.twitter.com/sfnet_ops/status/970316086959845382):

> **SourceForge SF.net Operations** @sfnet_ops · 6:12 PM · Mar 4, 2018
>   The issue affecting downloads and search has been resolved.

UbuntuZilla repository and corefonts works as expected.